# Lua eof for function,how to deduce number of end command and explainations

Tags: lua

```
function resolvecmd(cmdstr)     
    local func = c_tbl[cmdstr]
    userhistcmd[cmdcount]=userhistcmd   
    if(func) then
        return func()
    else if (advcmdsexist) then
            runadvcmd(cmdstr)   
        else
            c_tbl["listcmd"]()
        end 
    end 
end
```

above shows a function that is commonly used,
it is a function that access an index and does stuff with it,

At the same time there are some other boolean that affects the flow.

From my knowledge a `if...else if ..else` require a `end` statement.

then the function itself need a end statement.

However if you copy above script and just remove the last end statement,the interpreter will throw an error.

For confused brain:

```
expected,1(if else..)+1(func)=2(end needed)

reality,1(if else..)+1(func)+1(????what explain this????)=3(end needed)
```

Lastly,if you are too lazy to try removing the end and create those variabes and try it out yourself to verify

Here is a stock error result>

```
> lua: error loading module 'bsccmds' from file
> 'D:\Coding\lua\standardenv\bin\bsccmds.lua':
>         D:\Coding\lua\standardenv\bin\bsccmds.lua:39: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 24) near <eof> stack traceback:
>         [C]: in ?
>         [C]: in function 'require'
>         main.lua:2: in main chunk
>         [C]: in ?
```

Comment: Don't use `else if` in Lua; use `elseif`.

Comment: thanks that was magical.I suspect there is some difference to the interpreter then.Will wait for someone smart to explain some internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to see the problem if you place the `if` following the `else` on a separate line:

```
function resolvecmd(cmdstr)
  local func = c_tbl[cmdstr]
  userhistcmd[cmdcount]=userhistcmd
  if (func) then
    return func()
  else
    if (advcmdsexist) then
      runadvcmd(cmdstr)
    else
      c_tbl["listcmd"]()
    end
  end
end
```

The `if` following the `else` begins a new `if` statement requiring a new `end`. But Lua has the `elseif` keyword, which allows nested `if`s without the need for multiple `end`s:

```
function resolvecmd(cmdstr)
  local func = c_tbl[cmdstr]
  userhistcmd[cmdcount]=userhistcmd
  if (func) then
    return func()
  elseif (advcmdsexist) then
    runadvcmd(cmdstr)  
  else
    c_tbl["listcmd"]()
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you my mind is blown and this teached me a lesson.